# Link namecheap domain to IP

Tags: domains, web-hosting, url, dns, server

I just bought a domain at namecheap and I want to link it to my server's IP. I have set up port forwarding to the server to I think I just need to link the domain to the static IP.

These are my Host Records right now:

```
A Record: @ -> [SERVER IP]

CNAME Record: www -> parkingpage.namecheap.com

URL Redirect Record: @ -> [DOMAIN NAME]
```

I'm not sure if this is right, or whether I need to change/add stuff?

I also understand that DNS propagation can take a couple days, so does that mean i have to wait for two days to see if it worked? Or is there some way I can test it is redirecting to my server immediately?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The `A` record is set correctly.
The `CNAME` record should not point to the parking domain, but to your domain, simply set it to `@` so it will point to the server IP you've already set.
I don't know what is the URL redirect record you mentioned, if it's something you created by yourself, you should probably delete it.

DNS settings might take a while to get updated, and there's nothing you can do about it, as it depends on the caching of other DNS servers.
With that being said, a new domain is not cached and most likely will be updated within a few minutes.

Good luck with your new domain!